# Can one use \stanza within a quote environment?

Tags: reledmac

In the following example it can be seen that the line numbering is broken by the quote environment around the verse:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\setstanzaindents{3,2,2}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum[1]
\pend
\begin{quote}
  \stanza
  abc / &
  def // \&
\end{quote}
\pstart
\lipsum[2]
\pend
  \stanza
  abc / &
  def // \&
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image: verse in a quote]

The reledmac manual in its section on Quotation environments gives the following instruction:

> You must open any quotation environments inside a \pstart ... \pend
>   block, not outside.

Which I tried, but if I pull beginning and end of the quote environment before `\pend` and after `\pstart` respectively it doesn't compile at all.

Now I'm wondering what is the best way to include a piece of metric text, marked as a quote, in a longer prose passage. Maybe I should forget about using the `\stanza` command for it, the `stanzanum` counter not being necessary here, and just take care of the indentation manually?

Comment: for now, there is no possibility. please open a github issue, but I won't have time before a lot of time.